# (applescript) cant use command f

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

hi im working on a simple router cracker and this part won't compile (this is for searching the router ip so you can find its service provider) (if you get it)

```
tell application "Safari"
activate
open location "http://www.techspot.com/guides/287-default-router-ip-addresses/"
keystroke "f" using {command down, shift down}
set search to text returned of (display dialog "router ip" default answer "" buttons {"cancel", "find it"} default button 2)
search
keystroke "enter" using {command down, shift down}
```

Comment: You have to talk to "System Events" for keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

As DigiMonk said, the `keystroke` command is provided by System Events. You can also use UI scripting to fill the search field:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location "http://www.techspot.com/guides/287-default-router-ip-addresses/"
    set search to text returned of (display dialog "router ip" default answer "")
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "f" using command down
    tell process "Safari"
        tell group 1 of group 1 of window 1
            set value of text field 1 to search
            click button 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```